# Adding a column in R with dependent values

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  date = c("2001-1", "2001-2", "2001-3", "2001-1", "2001-2", "2001-3", "2001-1", "2001-2", "2001-3"),
  actor = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
  cat = c("I", "II", "III", "I", "II", "III", "I", "II", "III"),
  freq = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3)
)
```

I want to add another column (catNo):

```
Data["catNo"] <- NA
```

Now I want to replace the NAs in "catNo" with numbers (1-3) depending on the values in "cat" ("I" = 1, "II"=2, "III"=3).

How can I add these numbers, depending on the values in "cat"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have a vector of unique "strings" and an associated  vector for "numbers" you may want to try with:

```
strings <- c("a", "b" ,"d", "n")
numbers <- 1:4
x <- sample(l, 10, rep = T)
xf <- as.numeric(factor(x , levels = strings , labels = numbers))
```

Comment: that works, but only if I write the overwrite the values in "cat". But  I want to replace the NAs in "catNo" based on the entries in "cat".

Comment: Data[,"catNo"] <- Data$cat and then Data$catNo <- as.numeric(factor(Data$catNo, levels = categories , labels = categories2)) - Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you need a self made solution:

```
Data$catNo <- vapply(Data$cat, function(x) switch(x, I = 1, II = 2, III = 3, NA), FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))
```

note that it returns NA in case of no match

Comment: Ok, that works for 3 values, but I have 37! I have a list with all different values for "cat" and one list for all the numbers. Does this help?